# Функция, которая повторяет слово столько раз, сколько написал пользователь

Tags: python

```
x = input("Give a word: ")
y = int(input("Give a number: "))
```

Нужна функция, которая повторит слово в столбик столько раз, сколько ввел пользователь.

Вывод должен быть таким:

```
Give a word: sausage
Give a number: 6
sausage
sausage
sausage
sausage
sausage
sausage
```

Comment: `print(*(x for _ in range(y)), sep='\n')`, `print('\n'.join(x for _ in range(y)))`.

Comment: может лучше книжку прочитать ? там такое объясняют поняно

Answer (score 1):

```
string = input()
count = int(input())

def f0(string, count):
    for _ in range(count):
        print(string)

def f1(string, count):
    print(*[string] * count, sep = "\n")

def f2(string, count):
    print(*[string + "\n"] * count)

def f3(string, count):
    print("\n".join([string] * count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться повторением строк (т.е. `x * y` - то же, что записать строку `x` `y` раз подряд) вместе с конкатенацией строки с символом перевода строки, чтобы получить вывод столбик (т.е. `(x + '\n')`). Осталось объединить эти действия и отдать результат функции print